# Send encrypted request using Postman

Tags: json, encryption, postman

I am currently working on a Web application and need to send some request in JSON format to a servlet which I am testing through Postman.So, how can I send the encrypted request instead of the plain text transmission using Postman

Comment: Encrypted how?  You haven't given near enough information nor is your question about programming.  Please read the [help] so that you know what is on topic.

Comment: Most probably, encrypt (I dont have an idea what do you mean by encrypted, still..) the request content in your client application, copy the encrypted text and then paste it in Postman. Maybe.

Comment: @AjayGupta encoded in some way.. Base64 will also work fine in my case